# Sci-fi novel about a family that builds a dynasty using plant-based ceramics

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens

Seeking title of a novel about a human family who are given seeds from a plant which they can cheaply turn into ceramics.

A subplot is that the son of this family is a sociopath who experiments on the local alien population.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover? Also, from your description, it sounds like this is set in a human colony on another planet. Is that correct?